# How do I program a shared state without closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var state = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    // Do something depending on state
}, 1000)
```

Since everything can be done without closures, this is more of an intellectual exercise as I cannot see how to program something like this without closures. Do I pass state by reference into the anonymous function? (JavaScript doesn't support passing by reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a no-win answer, in that when you get down to it, there is absolutely no scope which doesn't create a closure; it's a question of whether the closure is used or not, and how it is used.

Closure is simply an inner scope which maintains reference to an outer scope.

Put it this way:

```
/* global */
window.incr_id = 0;
window.tick = 0;

function nextTick () { window.tick += 1; }

window.incr_id = window.setInterval(nextTick, 1000);
```

Does this count as closure, to you?

Technically, the global scope is the equivalent of running inside of a `Main ()` in other languages, therefore the `nextTick` function holds a reference to an outer-scope's value (`window`), causing a traversal up the chain of value tables, thus a "closure".

You could try something like

```
function nextTick () { nextTick.value += 1; }
nextTick.value = 0;
```

...but does that count, seeing as the self-reference comes from outside of the braces, and thus belongs in a higher scope?

```
function nextTick () { arguments.callee.value += 1; }
nextTick.value = 0;
```

Of course, that would thereby prevent you from using this solution in strict-mode (which you should use, if you expect to be safe).

You can, of course, create a closure which *isn't* the function in question, but rather, create monads, so that you're passing values incrementally through composed functions, rather than relying on closure references...

The problem there, of course, is that `setInterval` requires a function.
As such, whichever function you return to `setInterval`, that final function is going to have to use closure references, regardless of whether or not all your applicative functions did, prior.

And do function references count as closure references, if you reference a function which was not defined inside of your current function scope, or are we just talking about scalars?

Moral of the story:

```
window.value = 1;
window.obj.value = 1;

func.value = 0;
function func () { func.value = 1; }

function func () { arguments.callee.value = 1; }
```

The first two are valid if you're willing to concede that "window" can be referenced as not a closure (hint, it can't).

The last one might be valid if you're willing to accept that running in non-strict mode is bad for your clients, your audience, and your general health and wellbeing.

Comment: My takeaway from this is that closures are built in as part of the language and there is no way to avoid using them. I guess you can't write C-style code with JavaScript.

Comment: @allenylzhou I think you could operate without a closure.  Just never, ever use a function, or if you do, develop using only functions which pass and mutate objects and arrays, in place, as objects and arrays pass by reference, and never, ever ever use an async process, as that will, at some point require a variable reference to an outside scope.  "Closure" just means that a function can read variables outside of its scope; if you never reference a variable outside, you're never *using* the functionality. But it's like asking if you can write C without pointers...  Sure; ignore them (/suffer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything without closures. For example, state can be stored in an object with a designated method to "call the function". However, you will then need a different `setInterval()` function that takes your type of method, instead of the function type that it takes now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a variable by reference in JavaScript. You affect the higher level `var` by not using `var` inside a closure.

Simple Example:

```
var state = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
  state++; // state increases by one every second
}, 1000);
// should console.log(4)
setTimeout(function(){console.log(state)}, 4500);
```

If you did this:

```
var state = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var state = 0;
  state++; // state increases by one every second
  // state is 1 every time at this point
  // state outside closure is not affected
}, 1000);
// should console.log(0) - state refers to outside of closure
setTimeout(function(){console.log(state)}, 4500);
```

You can just think that every variable in JavaScript is passed by reference without even passing them as arguments, in a sense. In fact, if you do use a variable name as an argument it becomes redefined within the function you're passing it to, not affecting the variable at a higher level.

Passing an Anonymous function an argument, may or may no do anything depending on the situation. In the case of `setInterval()` is doesn't pass anything to the function you are passing to it. Note:

```
var state = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(arg){
  var state = 0;
  state++; // state increases by one every second
  // state is 1 every time at this point
  // state outside closure is not affected
}, 1000);
```

is the same as

```
var state = 0;
function what(arg){
  var state = 0;
  state++; // state increases by one every second
  // state is 1 every time at this point
  // state outside closure is not affected
}
var interval = setInterval(what, 1000);
```

So, really the function is passed into `setInterval()` without any arguments. Any arguments you put into `function what(){}` would have to be passed an argument by `setInterval()`, which passes no such argument.

Check this out:

```
function whatever(func){
  // takes function argument like `setInterval()`
  // need to pass it something to have func take an argument
  func("We'll just pass our function this String");
}
whatever(console.log); // now console.log() is passed an argument
```

So, you can see that the function that takes your function as an argument decides what arguments the function that is passed as an argument gets passed.

Comment: Well, I want the state to be shared (The first code snippet) and I'm wondering if it can be done without the use of a closure in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I pass state by reference into the anonymous function?

Yes. Although `setInterval` is very complicated to do without "closure", as it doesn't really allow you pass anything.

> JavaScript doesn't support passing by reference

Yes. We won't use references to variables, but an object to store the state. Instead of modifying closure variables, you'll modify the passed object.

```
var state = {
    value: 0
};
state.interval = setInterval(function() { 
    // Do something depending on this.value
}.bind(state), 1000);
```